# How can I stop iPad cords from getting bent and broken?

Tags: technology, cables

My iPad cords keeps getting bent and it ends up being broken. It is annoying that I have to go to the store again and again because of broken cords.

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What do you mean by breaking? Physical breakage? electrical failure? what are you doing to them? where do they fail? Please read the [help center](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) regarding what this site is about, and if you can clarify how we can help you specifically, please edit your post and 'flag' to reopen. Thank you.

Comment: Simply add a picture. I know what you're talking about.